linebreak skipping two lines on the title of my charts on MS Excel
I made a VBA code to create some charts and when I coded the title, I used the normal:
    .title = studentname & vbCrLf & "Grades on test X"

but the output came out like this:

John Smith
Grades on test X

with two spaces instead of my intended output which would be like:

John Smith 
Grades on test X

chatgpt couldn't help me and I don't know what to do.

Try using vbLf instead of vbCrLf.

Are you also inferring that if you don't include the "vbCrLf" that you just get the resulting string on a single line?  (If not, perhaps there's a "hidden" line-break character at the end of your student name?)

@Craig yes, without the vbCrLf everything gets on the same line (so no hidden linebreak), I am yet to test the alternative provided by MGonet

@Craig MGonet's answer worked out for me
